# How do I avoid an error when trying to create multiple live tiles using the Windows Phone ShellTile API?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, code-behind, live-tile

Starting off with the example [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Building-Dynamic-Live-52bdc195), I created an app to pin multiple tiles to the Start screen. When I pin the first tile, I have no issues. However, when I return to the app (via the app list or the back key), and click on a second image to pin the second tile, I get an InvalidOperationException.

Here is my simple code:

```
    private void Pin_Tile1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StandardTileData data1 = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/tile1.png", UriKind.Relative),
            Title = "Tile 1",
            BackContent = "asdf"
        };

        ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), data1);
    }

    private void Pin_Tile2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StandardTileData data20 = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/tile2.png", UriKind.Relative),
            Title = "Tile 2",
            BackContent = "fdsa"
        };
        ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), data2); 

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Thanks for looking

Comment: Haha, I messed up. Fixed now :)

Comment: Where are you getting the error, code for tile looks OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/11/31-days-of-mango-day-11-live-tiles/), each live tile must point to a unique Uri, that is where I messed up.

Full list of requirements is:

- Each Live Tile must point to a unique URI location.
- Each time that you create a secondary tile, the user will be taken to
  their home    screen to view it.  You can’t create more than one
  secondary tile at    a time.
- Limit the number of secondary live tiles allowed.